# Creating a connection between two decoupled components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to find a way to create a connection between a component, and a child component that is completely decoupled.

For instance, if I have two components, `parent-component`, and `child-component` that will only ever exist inside `parent-component` in the markup, I need to find a way for `parent-component` and `child-component` to communicate both ways.

So for instance if I have the following markup:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

I need a way for the parent component to reference the state of each of the child components, and each of the child components to reference the state of the parent component.

Is there a way to do this in Angular 2? I've dug around everywhere, and I can't really find a solution.

Comment: sounds like you need a service.

Comment: It's covered in the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Was trying to avoid using a service, but if that's the only way then so be it. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a parent an child to communicate with one another the Angular2 recommendation is to use a service. This is covered in the cookbook : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service