# What is the proper way to make interaction in two isolated components?

Tags: angular

[Components Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssa35.png)

In above image there are 4 components A, B, C and D. There are multiple ways to make interaction in direct child-parent components. But I want to know how to make interaction in isolated components like C and D in above scenario.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: You can use service. Check this: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022115/creating-a-connection-between-two-decoupled-components)